# Two clone variables return the same index on a list

Tags: c#, list, clone

I have a list which has a number of objects from class X.

I add one object via `clone` function, it gets its own index, but if I add one more object using the clone, the object receives the same index as the first clone.

Here some code:

```
public void AddCopyObj(List<x> MyList, int Idx)
{
  x AddCloneObj=MyList[Idx].Clone();
  MyList.Insert(Idx+1,AddCloneObj)
}

public List<int> GetAllIndexs(List<x> MyList)
{
  List<int> IndexList = new List<int>();
  foreach(x myXvar in MyList)
  {
    IndexList.add(MyList.IndexOf(myXvar));
  }
  return IndexList ;
}
```

**For example**: If I have 10 objects to one of them I made twice clone, I will have 12 objects and index of both the clone be the same (they do not sit on the same index, the function IndexOf returns the same one)

What can I do?

**EDIT:**

```
public x Clone()
    {
        x clone = new x(Int32.Parse(this.Name.Split(new char[1] { ' ' })[1]) + 1);
        clone.Copy(this);
        return clone;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the implementation of `x.Clone()`.

Comment: Yep, and also do you implement IEquatable for X?

Comment: @hodaya The code sample seems a little odd, what is the end goal of this code? I get the impression there may be a simpler way to achieve your requirement.

Comment: It's not my code, so they brought it to me and I can not change. (Only use)

Comment: Does the class X implement IEquatable?

Comment: No. class x has an INotifyPropertyChange implementation, that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I did not do twice clone,

I took the same object and put it twice in the list,

after I had done twice clone issue is resolved.

**(Sorry, it was not on a question, you could not tell.)**

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from MSDN (emphasis my own):

> Searches for the specified object and returns the zero-based index of
>   the **first occurrence** within the range of elements in the List that
>   extends from the specified index to the last element.

They are both matching the first occurrence basically. This boils down to equality on the items you have in `List<>`, it uses the default equality comparer:

> This method determines equality using the default equality comparer
>   EqualityComparer.Default for T, the type of values in the list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx

You could use the override that takes a starting index to preclude prior indices from the search:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8t42k5w.aspx

Or, if you want to hold unique items based on hash and equality, use `HashSet<T>` instead.

I thought about offering a code sample, however when I look at the code you provide it makes less and less sense. You current sample will loop the items in index order and add the index to another list, only for duplicate items it'll be the same index. Taking a step back, ***what are you trying to achieve?*** I get the sense there's a better option.

Comment: Assuming I can not do one of two options you brought (reasons not change now) no other way to get the real index?

Comment: @HodayaShalom You can get the index of the item you are iterating by using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`. I am struggling to see what this code is trying to achieve. Alternatively, if you keep track of how far through the list you are, the `IndexOf` override option will work for you.

Comment: It's a bit complicated to explain why I can not use it, but I'll try. Basically I make line numbers to a wpf DataGrid by converter (according to my list) in converter I have the whole list and only item that should have a line number. Therefore I can not use the suggestions you brought, because I have no index started to send.

Comment: The default equality comparer compares REFERENCES, so if the class X does NOT implement IEquatable then the OP's code should work (since it should be finding the item by comparing references, not values, and the references are different by virtue of the Clone call). I conclude that class X has an IEquatable implementation that we're not being told about.

Comment: class x has an INotifyPropertyChange  implementation

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree, or x is really a value type, Tuple, or anonymous type or something. Either way, missing lots of the story and/or not enough information to answer, so I'm bowing out.